# Apple Search Ads rate limit

Tags: rate-limiting, apple-search-ads

The official documentation of Apple Search Ads does not mention any rate limits. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_search_ads , but while trying to call the API through a script, I ran into 429 responses. Where can the official rate limit be found for ASA ?